# Which preposition should I choose for "lunch"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm reading kids' textbook.

The question is "Which preposition should you choose?"

> We drank the milk ___ lunch.

Is the blank ***at,  to,  in,***  or ***on***?

The book provides those four options.

Answer (score 1):

"At lunch" is an idiom that means "while we were eating lunch." More broadly, it may mean the time immediately before eating or immediately after eating but at a place associated with eating such as a restaurant.

"At" is usually an indicator of place. I suspect (but do not have a citation) that "at lunch" etc. derive from the old fashioned phrase "at table," meaning "sitting at a table while eating a meal."

Comment: Thank you for answering!! That makes sense!! The problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Of those four options, the only one that sounds correct and idiomatic is *at*:

> We drank the milk **at** lunch.

As another answer already points out, *at lunch* is idiomatic, and the phrase basically means *at lunchtime*.

---

I can think of ways to alter the sentence such that some of the other prepositions would be the best fit:

> - We drank the milk **on** our lunch break.
> - We drank the milk **in** the lunchroom.

The phrase *on break* is similar to *at lunch*; it refers to the time spent on a break.

---

There are other prepositions that would also fit:

> 1. We drank the milk **during** lunch.
> 2. We drank the milk **with** lunch.
> 3. We drank the milk **for** lunch.

That third sentence (with *for*) implies that milk was the meal itself, not just the beverage served with lunch. Normally, this would be an unusual sentence, unless perhaps the speaker was participating in some diet plan where a glass of milk was supposed to be a substitute for a full meal. But this sentence would not sound odd at all:

> We drank the smoothie **for** lunch.

Comment: Thank you a lot for thinking about options and other prepositions!! I should have noticed your question and answered it yesterday: ( But I'm very happy to see your great explaining about it!! I understand it!! I appliciate your kindness!

Comment: @Mana - No problem, but don't leave too many thank-you comments. [Here's why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/are-thanks-for-the-answers-unnecessary).